# Catch errors caused by specific methods at runtime [in java]

Tags: java, exception

I'm currently writing a java application and I need to get all the exceptions that will be thrown by some specific classes methods at runtime and log them to a file or database. So the idea that came to my head is to use an annotation ,[@traceable] for example, to annotate the classes that i need to capture the exceptions that will be thrown by the methods declared in them and try by some way to capture just the exceptions that was thrown by a method of a class that is annotated with the custom annotation , @traceable in this case.

The idea is in my head but I didn't found any way to implement it, even using reflection i can't catch those exceptions.

So, i wonder if some one could help me out with the problem by explaining to me how can I achieve that using my idea Or by proposing another solution.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You probably should look into AspectJ, unless these classes are already proxyable components used in a dependency injection framework like Spring or CDI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use spring aop to intercept all exceptions.

https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-aop/aspectj-afterthrowing-annotation-example/